# Furnace will occasionally not turn on unless thermostat temp is increased

Tags: furnace, humidifier, temperature

Occasionally (mostly in the morning) my furnace will not turn on. I have it set to 72. When I wake up the house temperature has dropped to say 64 or 65. If I turn the thermostat up to say 74, the furnace will startup. It will also start up if I turn the thermostat off then on. Sometimes I’ll have to do this once or twice. After that, it appears to work fine the rest of the day.

This issue *appears* to have started after I installed a humidifier.

Thermostat: Honeywell Home, Model# RTH9585WF1004

Furnace: Coleman Echelon 9.S series

Humidifier: Aprilaire 600 with Automatic Controller Model 60.

As part of the humidifier install I hooked up wires as:

**Furnace** ——————->**Humidifier**

R——————————->               R (power)

C———————————>               C (power)

G———————————>               Gr (outputs)

W———————————>               W (inputs)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the hysteresis setting?  To avoid "chatter,"  a thermostat will not turn the furnace on until the temperature has dropped X degrees below the setpoint.  Your value of "X" might be extreme.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for the input Carl. I don’t think that would be the issue. I’ve not touched the thermostat and it has been working for weeks prior to this (unless my wife messed with it...Hmmm). Thanks.